# How to check if a class has a specific base class in Matlab

Tags: matlab, class, oop, inheritance

I define in Matlab a class that's a subclass of another one, like this:

```
classdef SpecificLimit < BaseLimit

  % Private properties section
  properties (SetAccess = private, GetAccess = private)
    options;
  end

  % Public section
  methods (Access = public)
    % ...
  end
end
```

Now I've a variable named `r` and I want to check if this variable is a class instance that has `BaseLimit` as base class (I've a lot of them). Is there an easy way to do that? I've read about `meta.class` but I didn't find a way to perform this check.

I'm using Matlab r2014a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [superclasses](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/superclasses.html)

Something like:

```
 any ( strcmp ( superclasses ( 'SpecificLimit' ), 'BaseLimit' ) )
```

Comment: @Suever has a better answer.

Answer (score 7):

You should use [`isa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isa.html) which determines if an object is either a `BaseLimit` instance or is derived from `BaseLimit`.

```
isa(r, 'BaseLimit')
```